error-500-after-successful-authentication-b2c-when-hosted-on-ionos-widows
I had configure project blazor webapp .net 8 with server render and azure b2c. App work on Azure App Service and locally. When publish on IONOS host, after login, redirect on .../signin-oidc return 502 bad gateway.
On IONOS, it necessary to add proxy to call Azure b2c, maybe it's the problem.
can you help me.
May be same problem Error 500 after successful authentication OAuth 2.0 when hosted on IONOS widows
    var proxy = new WebProxy()
    {
        Address = new Uri("http://winproxy.server.lan:3128/"),
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,        
    };


    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

            if (!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    UseProxy = true,
                    Proxy = proxy,
                    PreAuthenticate = true,
                };                
            }

Publish project on Azure OK.
Antiforgery Disabled change nothing.
2024-04-24 edit : some additional details
url : https://.b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=30ae9bc&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpocb2cdotnet8blazorwasm.naopro.net%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=*****RjZDgx&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.2.17.5.0&state=Cf*zhtV&x-client-SKU=ID_NET8_0&x-client-ver=7.5.0.0
result.
screenshot
